# Set selection at beginning of spinner with simplecursoradapter

Tags: android, database, spinner

I have an activity A with a listView. I've got a few items in there. If I click in one of those items, I navigate with an Intent to another page. In that other poage/Activity, I have a spinner, which contains the items of the listView ( which is populated with database). The problem is, every time, i go to that activity B, the item displayed in the spinner is always the first in my database. How can I set the item to be displayed depending on the item I clicked in the listView ?

Here's how I populate my spinner (dropdown mode) :

```
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_branches);
    final Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getAllCours();
    String[] from = { "branche_cours" }; int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 };
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to, 0);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

When I navigate, i pass the selected item with the intent. I remind you that my listView contains the same items of the spinner..

```
String selected_brancheold= intent.getExtras().getString("branche");
```

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one thing if your ListView list and Spinner List both are same.

Activity A

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_CONTEXT, ActivityB.class);
    intent.putExtra("position",PASS_CURRENT_POSITION_LISTVIEW_ITEM_CLICKED);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Activity B (After setting up the spinner adapter)

```
    int currentPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0);
    spinner.setSelection(currentPosition);
```

Hope this works for you!!

Comment: Thank you sir ! It worked ! Also, may I ask you one more thing : in the future I will use more spinners.. How can I set at the beginning the value "Select One" ? I'll use simplecursoradapter as well

Comment: Happy to help!! This seems like the new question. I suggest you to add separate question for this.

Comment: I saw now while testing that it's not correct.. I mean, now it keeps returning the last value, can you please help me ? How should I get the position on my listView ?

Comment: well nvm, I figured it out ! Thank you for helping me ! And sorry for yesterday's loss ;)